# When I execute my program, it shuts down

Tags: c, data-structures

When I execute my program, it shuts down. After it compiles, the program window opens up, then I can enter the client's ID, after that, it freezes, then a new pop-up says that the program has stopped working, and needs to close. I have isolated the problem to this line, first = middle + 1; Any help would be much appreciated. The program is built to run in C, on Dev C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct//Declares structure to hold seven created datatypes.
{
    int client_id;
    char client_business_name [30];
    char client_first_name [20];
    char client_last_name [20];
    char client_address [40];
    float client_budget;
    char client_business_info [300];
}Client;

main()
{
    Client c[100];
    int y;
    printf ("\nEnter Client ID:");
    scanf ("%d",&c[y].client_id);
    printf ("Enter Buisness Name:");
    scanf (" %[^\n]",c[y].client_business_name);
    printf ("Enter Client First Name:");
    scanf (" %[^\n]",c[y].client_first_name);     
    printf ("Enter Client Last Name:");
    scanf (" %[^\n]",c[y].client_last_name);     
    printf ("Enter Buisness Address:");
    scanf (" %[^\n]",c[y].client_address);
    printf ("Enter Client Budget:");
    scanf ("%f",&c[y].client_budget);
    printf ("Enter Buisness Information:");
    scanf (" %[^\n]",c[y].client_business_info);

    printf ("ID:%d\n",c[y].client_id);

    int key,max=100;
    printf ("\nEnter Client ID To Be Deleted:");
    scanf ("%d",&key);
    system ("cls");
    int first = 0;
    int last = max - 1;
    int middle = (first+last)/2;
    while( first <= last )
    {
        if (c[middle].client_id < key)
            first = middle + 1;    
        else if (c[middle].client_id == key) 
        { 
            c[middle].client_id=c[middle+1].client_id;
            strcpy(c[middle].client_business_name,c[middle+1].client_business_name);
            strcpy(c[middle].client_first_name,c[middle+1].client_first_name);
            strcpy(c[middle].client_last_name,c[middle+1].client_last_name);
            strcpy(c[middle].client_address,c[middle+1].client_address);
            c[middle].client_budget=c[middle+1].client_budget;
            strcpy(c[middle].client_business_info,c[middle+1].client_business_info);                     
            printf ("\nClient Removed!");  
            break;
        }
        else
            last = middle - 1;
        middle = (first + last)/2;
    }
    if ( first > last )
    {
        printf ("\nClient Not Registered\n");
    }
    system ("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: That line doesn't look like a problem...

Comment: 1) the main declaration needs to be 'int main()' not 'main()'  2) the #include<stdlib.h> is missing, so the system function: 'system()' is undefined  3) the variable 'y' is used before being set to a known value    Fix these problems, post the corrected code  Then we would be better able to help you

Comment: some time with a debugger would show the problem with the code logic.

Comment: the returned value from scanf() (and family) should always be checked to assure the input/conversion operations were successful

Comment: this code seems to be preforming a binary search on a ordered list, then when the target record is found, copies the next record onto the target record.  While this will 'remove' the target record information, it does not removed the actual record.  Now, there is a duplicate of the next record.  I.E. the list did not get smaller, it only duplicated another record.  Suggest making this a ordered linked list,  then unlinking the target record and passing the pointer to the target record to free() then the list record will actually be removed without creating duplicates

Comment: the variable 'y' is not initialized, so the scanf data could be going anywhere.  Only one record is being entered, (there is also no facility to sort the data)   So, with only one record entered, all other records in the array are initialized garbage/trash.  The variable 'max' is using the full size of the array, rather than the actual size (which in this case is 1)  suggest entering records in a loop, suggest adding a facillity to sort the array in place, suggest using a linked list rather than an array so a record delete can actually work

Answer (score 0):

```
 while( first <= last )
 {
    if (c[middle].client_id < key)
       first = middle + 1;  
    else if (c[middle].client_id == key)
```

You're not recomputing middle in the if clause. So if you enter that clause, you'll set first to middle + 1, then you'll spin around the loop again, and middle is the same value. So you'll just do it again, and again, and that's why you hang. That clause doesn't advance your loop. Try updating middle like you do in the else clause.

Comment: Thank you, I had not thought of that

Answer (score -1):

1. the `main` declaration needs to be `int main()` not `main()`
2. the `#include <stdlib.h>` is missing, so the system function: `system()` is undefined
3. the variable `y` is used before being set to a known value

Fix these problems, post the corrected code.
Then we would be better able to help you.

The compile step needs to always enable all warnings; 
warnings are messages from the compiler that it thinks there is a problem.
Those warnings are important.
Fix the code so it does not produce warnings during the compile step.

In general, 
you are wasting your time linking/running code that compiled with warnings.

This `typedef`:

```
typedef struct //Declares structure to hold seven created datatypes.
{
    int client_id;
    char client_business_name [30];
    char client_first_name [20];
    char client_last_name [20];
    char client_address [40];
    float client_budget;
    char client_business_info [300];
}Client;
```

is not a good way to define a struct.
A struct should never be `typedef`d 
as that just clutters the code, clutters the compiler name space
and does not help to implement any algorithm.

Here is a good way to define a struct:

```
struct  Client //Declares structure to hold seven created datatypes.
{
    int client_id;
    char client_business_name [30];
    char client_first_name [20];
    char client_last_name [20];
    char client_address [40];
    float client_budget;
    char client_business_info [300];
};
```

Then all references to the struct should be written as:
`struct Client ...`

Comment: You're allowed to prefer not to use a simple name for a structure, and the Linux kernel follows that style, but it is not generally regarded as unacceptable.  It is more questionable whether to use `typedef struct { … } TypeName;` or `typedef struct TypeName { … } TypeName;` — both work when you actually define the structure type.  If you are defining an opaque type, you must use `typedef struct TypeName TypeName;` of course.